# How to match repeated sequences using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, sequence

I want to use the javascript replace() function and regex to replace parts of a string.

I have a string similar to this

```
(x=(1.22|2|3) && za=(hello|world|there|wow)||yy=(2|3))
```

The end goal is to turn it into the following using javascript

```
(x=1.22|2|3 && za=hello|world|there|wow||yy=2|3)
```

I am trying to use the replace() method with regex and capture group.
Where I am getting stuck is the regex.
I can capture the `something=`, which I use `(\w+=)` to capture.
But I couldn't figure out how to capture the content within the parentheses

```
1.22|2|3
hello|world|there|wow
2|3
```

Those values delimited by `|` can be string, integer or decimals.
I've tried things like --

```
/(\w*\.?\w+\|\w*\.?\w+)/g
```

But that would only capture groups of `something|something`. So for `1.22|2|3`, only `1.22|2` would be captured.
I've tried different variations of that regex, and couldn't figure out how to capture all of the `|` delimited content.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `s = s.replace(/(\w=)\([^()]+)\)/g, "$1$2")`

Comment: I guess, what are you capturing? I don't understand. To go from your initial to your result looks like you're just removing parens?

Comment: That's it. I want to remove the parens when I detect patterns of `something=(something|something|...)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unmatched `)`

Comment: Right, but I think you're missing the point of the question. Instead of trying so hard to match anything, why don't you just remove all but the surrounding parens in the string? Is there a reason you need to match these things?

Comment: Yeah, `s = s.replace(/(\w=)\(([^()]+)\)/g, "$1$2")`, one opening `(` was missing. Or, if ther must be a pipe char inside parentheses, ``s = s.replace(/(\w=)\(([^()|]+(?:\|[^()|]+)+)\)/g, "$1$2")``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are awesome. `(\w+=)\([^()]+\)` Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replace(/(\w=)\(([^()]+)\)/g, "$1$2");
```

**Details**

- `(\w=)` - Group 1: a word char and a `=`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MqOwH2/1).

Or, if ther must be a pipe char inside parentheses, use

```
s = s.replace(/(\w=)\(([^()|]+(?:\|[^()|]+)+)\)/g, "$1$2");
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MqOwH2/2). Here, Group 2 pattern is different from the first pattern:

- `[^()|]+` - 1 or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `|`
- `(?:\|[^()|]+)+` - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `\|` - a pipe char
  - `[^()|]+` - 1 or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `|`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. They are both awesome.

Comment: Sorry. Just did.